# How to create a horizontal line above and below an entire table environment?

Tags: tables

I have several tables in a document and I would like to add a horizontal line across the page above and below the entire `table` environment. I can get the desired output with `\hrule` and some extra spacing, but I'd like to be able to define a format that does this to use for all tables, rather than manually add the lines. Here's an example of my desired output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}

\begin{document}

text
\vspace{5mm}\hrule
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        a & a\\
        a & a
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{something}
    \label{something}
\end{table}
\hrule\vspace{5mm}
text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks

Edit: Additionally, is there a way to change the spacing depending on whether the following content is text or an equation? If I had an equation instead of text either directly above or directly below the table, I would remove the corresponding `\vspace{5mm}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `environ` package, you can define your own `table` environment based off of the original `table` plus your required additions. The `ruledtable`, e.g., can be defined like this:

```
\NewEnviron{ruledtable}{%
\par\addvspace{5mm}\hrule
\begin{table}[!h]\BODY\end{table}
\hrule\addvspace{5mm}
}
```

In this case, you will only change all instances of `\begin{table} .. \end{table}` in your text to the new `\begin{ruledtable} .. \end{ruledtable}` without any additional manual modifications.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{ruledtable}{%
\par\addvspace{5mm}\hrule
\begin{table}[!h]\BODY\end{table}
\hrule\addvspace{5mm}
}

\begin{document}

text
\begin{ruledtable}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        a & a\\
        a & a
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{something}
    \label{something}
\end{ruledtable}
text


\begin{equation}
x + y = 5
\end{equation}
\begin{ruledtable}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        a & a\\
        a & a
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{something2}
    \label{something2}
\end{ruledtable}
\begin{equation}
x + y = 5
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! `\addvspace` seems like a useful command.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` commands in your table from the booktabs package. That looks very clean

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve OP problem.